# Xcodebuild: Failed to load Addressbook

Tags: ios, macos, xcodebuild, carthage

When I used carthage, build always faild, So I search carthage github issues, I found it seems to be xcodebuild error, Even though, I input `xcodebuild -list` it will throw error

`~$ > xcodebuild -list
2016-03-02 10:40:17.413 xcodebuild[17993:2398778] ### Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter
Information about project "ReactiveCocoa":
    Targets:
        ReactiveCocoa-Mac
        ReactiveCocoa-MacTests
        ReactiveCocoa-iOS`

I have no idea about this, Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter` is emitted from xcodebuild even when everything succeeds.

You can ignore it. Would be nice to find a way to squelch it.